# Restoring OpenGL State

Tags: c++, c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I want to write a general purpose utility function that will use an OpenGL Framebuffer Object to create a texture that can be used by some OpenGL program for whatever purpose a third party programmer would like.

Lets say for argument stake the function looks like

```
void createSpecialTexture(GLuint textureID)
{
    MyOpenGLState state;
    saveOpenGLState(state);
    setStateToDefault();
    doMyDrawing();
    restoreOpenGLState(state);
}
```

What should `MyOpenGLState`,  `saveOpenGLState(state)`, `setStateToDefault()` and `restoreOpenGLState(state)` look like to ensure that `doMyDrawing` will behave correctly and that nothing that I do in `doMyDrawing` will affect anything else that a third party developer might be doing?

The problem that has been biting me is that OpenGL has a lot of implicit state and I am not sure I am capturing it all.

**Update**: My main concern is OpenGL ES 2.0 but I thought I would ask the question more generally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a framebuffer object to render your texture. Rather create a new EGLContext and EGLSurface. You can then use `eglBindTexImage` to turn your EGLSurface into a texture. This way you are guaranteed that state from `doMyDrawing` will not pollute the main gl Context and visa versa.

Answer (score 1):

As for saving and restoring, `glPushAttrib` and `glPopAttrib` will get you very far.

You cannot, however, restore GL to a default state. However, since `doMyDrawing()` uses and/or modifies only state that should be known to you, you can just set that to values that you need.

Comment: The question mainly concerns OpenGL ES 2.0, which neither `glPushAttrib` or `glPopAttrib` is a part of (see http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/).

Answer (score 0):

That depends a lot on what yo do on your `doMyDrawing();`, but basically you have to restore *everything* (all states) that you change in this function. Without having a look at what is going on inside `doMyDrawing();` it is impossible to guess what you have to restore.

If modifications on the projection or modelview matrix are done inside `doMyDrawing()`, remember to go initially push both `GL_PROJECTION` and `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix through `glPushMatrix` and restore them after the drawing through `glPopMatrix`. Any other state that you modify can be push and pop though `glPushAttrib` and the right attribute. Remember also to unbind any texture, FBO, PBO, etc.. that you might bind inside doMyDrawing();

Comment: Note that glPush/Pop* don't exist in OpenGLES 2.0